# What does 50% RH mean?

Tags: materials, plastic

I'm looking to determine the difference between the two yield strengths on a Matweb material property table for [DuPont Performance Polymers Zytel® 105F BK010 PA66](http://www.matweb.com/search/datasheet.aspx?matguid=77b8eca6a7324775827b768f95637200). The top is for "50% RH; ISO 527-1/-2" per the comments and the bottom is "DAM;ISO 527-1/-2". I need to know what 50% RH and DAM mean so I can make an informed decision. Any help would be appreciated.

[image: Image from Matweb Table]

Comment: 50% relative humidity is the half the maximum capacity of air to hold water at a particular temperature. Look up psychrometric chart for details.

Comment: DAM is probably an abbreviation for "Dry as moulded".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

DAM means "dry as manufactured" or "dry as moulded", i.e. the material is in its moisture-free state immediately after manufacture. The DAM moisture content is typically less than 0.2%.

"50% RH" means the material has absorbed moisture from an environment with 50% relative humidity until it has reached an equilibrium state.

Answer (score 1):

[The relative humidity](https://www.nfsa.gov.au/preservation/preservation-glossary/relative-humidity-rh) (RH) is the ratio of the actual water vapour pressure to the saturation water vapour pressure at the prevailing temperature. For example – if a cubic metre can hold 100ml of water at 20 degrees centigrade (273 K) and it does contain 100ml then it is said to be 100% RH. If the same cubic metre of air at the same temperature only contains 50mls of water then it is described as 50% RH.

$\rm{RH = \frac{p}{p_s}}$

[DAM Meaning](https://acronym24.com/dam-meaning/) is: Dry As Molded.